# Use the extended euclidean algortithm to solve this inverse?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Having trouble with understanding this.

$$d \equiv 7^{-1} \pmod {360}$$

So far i have got

$$360 = 7 \cdot 51 + 3$$

$$7 = 3 \cdot 2 + 1$$

$$3 = 3 \cdot 1 + 0$$

Now i am stuck on the next step have looked at a few videos but have had no luck

Comment: I highly recommend instead using [this form](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242) of the Extended Euclidean Algorithm. Not only is it easier, but it is far less error-prone than the back-substitution method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your first two equations,

$\begin{array}{rcl} 3&=&360-7\cdot51\\ 1&=&7-3\cdot 2\end{array}$

Now substitute:
$$1 = 7-3\cdot 2=7-(360-7\cdot 51)\cdot 2 = 7\cdot 103-360\cdot 2$$
Considering this last equation $\mod{360}$, we get $1\equiv 7\cdot 103 \pmod{360}$.  So $7^{-1}\equiv 103\pmod{360}$

---

Another format for doing this problem is 
$$\begin{array}{c|r|r} &x&7x\pmod{360} \\ \hline 
&0&360 \\
&1 & 7\\ 
\text{Row 3}=\text{Row 1}-51\cdot\text{Row 2}& -51&3\\  
\text{Row 4} =\text{Row 2}  - 2\cdot\text{Row 3} & 103 & 1  
\end{array}$$

Comment: thanks for this...just wondering how you got to 103? 7 * 103?

Comment: @luke1892 Basically you are doing row operations on the table.  The first two rows are 0, modulus; and 1, number you want the inverse of.  To get Row n (from rows n-1 and n-2) you subtract the largest multiple of row n-2 that you can from row n-1 while keeping the rightmost column value positive.  If you can't get to 1 in the right most column, your number isn't invertible with respect to the given modulus.  (This is a variant of a gcd algorithm that gives the gcd as a linear (integer) combination of the inputs.